# Having problems with inner joins in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, inner-join

```
var result=from stdnt in students
           join lssn in lessons on new {number ==stdnt.state==true ? stdnt.newnumber : s.oldnumber}
equals new {number ==stdnt.state==true ? lssn.newnumber : lssn.oldnumber}
 select new {.... };
```

'lssn' name 'equals' operator does not respect the right side. 'equals' operator in expressions consider changing sides.

Comment: The expression on the RHS of `equals` uses `stdnt` - it's not allowed to. It would really help if you'd explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your query:

```
var reslt = from stdnt in students
            join lssn in lessons on (stdnt.state ? stdnt.newnumber : stdnt.oldnumber)
            equals (lssn.state ? lssn.newnumber : lssn.oldnumber)
            select new { ... };
```

Comment: var reslt = from stdnt in students
            join lssn in lessons on (stdnt.state ? stdnt.newnumber : stdnt.oldnumber)
            equals (stdnt.state ? lssn.newnumber : lssn.oldnumber)
            select new { ... };